# in C# code (WPF project) can I raise an event at a specific point in a storyboard

Tags: c#, wpf, events, storyboard

I have a storyboard that runs forever with autoreverse for lets say 10 seconds.

Is there anyway I can get the storyboard itself to raise an event every 2 seconds along the storyboard timeline.

the storyboard only exists in c# code (not xaml).

I hope that this is enough to go on, but, if more information is needed please ask and I will explain what i am doing.

thanks in advance

Dan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of events provided by the storyboard timeline which may help... something like :

```
private Storyboard stb = new Storyboard();
private TimeSpan tsp = new TimeSpan();

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    stb.CurrentTimeInvalidated += new EventHandler(doSomething);            
}

private void doSomething(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Clock storyboardClock = (Clock)sender;
        // or whatever other logic you want
    if (storyboardClock.CurrentTime.Value.Seconds % 2 == 0 && 
       Math.Abs((storyboardClock.CurrentTime.Value - tsp).TotalSeconds) >= 2)
    {
        // or something like this...
        tsp = storyboardClock.CurrentTime.Value
         - new TimeSpan(0,0,0,0,storyboardClock.CurrentTime.Value.Milliseconds);
        // do something
    }
}
```

Check out :

[MSDN - CurrentTimeInvalidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.currenttimeinvalidated%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[MSDN - CurrentStateInvalidated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.currentstateinvalidated%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)